# Add Value to Textarea Only If Empty

Tags: jquery, wordpress, input, textarea

I'm building a form in WordPress that includes a textarea that may or may not have a value, depending on the client's input. To make it easy for the client, I've re-purposed a checkbox to dynamically hide this textarea field if the checkbox is toggled. It also dynamically changes the label to say "Specified/Not Specified."

The last remaining component for this field that I cannot figure out is as follows: when the client toggles the checkbox off **AND** there's no existing value in the textarea, I'd like the value to be entered as 'Not Specified'. Conversely, if the value in the textarea ***is precicely*** 'Not Specified', then the value should be cleared when the checkbox is toggled to enable.

What I want to prevent is for my client to enter a value into the textbox, toggle the checkbox off, and accidentally clear anything they may have entered. Similarly, if the toggle is switched on, from a UI perspective it should no longer say 'Not Specified'.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="directorist-custom-field-checkbox">             
                
    <div class="directorist-checkbox directorist-mb-10" id="special-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Yes-3727648641" name="special-checkbox[]" value="Yes">
        <label for="Yes-3727648641" class="" id="special-checkbox-label">Special Instructions Specified</label>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="directorist-custom-field-textarea">
    <textarea name="special-textarea" id="special-textarea" class="directorist-form-element" rows="3" placeholder=""></textarea>    
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='special-checkbox[]']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#special-textarea").hide();                
            $("#special-textarea").val('Not specified');           
            $("label#special-checkbox-label").html("Special Instructions Not Specified");
        } else {
            $("#special-textarea").show();
            $("label#special-checkbox-label").html("Special Instructions Specified");
        }
    });
});
```

Shown above just enters 'Not specified' when the textarea is hidden. And if something is entered and then hidden, then it replaces it with 'Not specified'. What I've tried so far (without luck) is a nested if inside the "parent" if statement, but when I publish the .js file and run it, the page hangs. Is there a "cleaner" and actually workable solution that would fit my requirements?

P.S. The reason I'm using the input name instead of the ID is that Wordpress (or the theme) dynamically change the ID to a random number every time the page loads so I had to grab another static attribute from the element.

Answer (score 0):

As per code you need to add clearing the text field after it's checked again.

Try below snippet

```js
$(function () {
    $("input[name='special-checkbox[]']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#special-textarea").hide();                
            $("#special-textarea").val('Not specified');           
            $("label#special-checkbox-label").html("Special Instructions Not Specified");
        } else {
            $("#special-textarea").show();
            $("#special-textarea").val('');
            $("label#special-checkbox-label").html("Special Instructions Specified");
      $("#special-textarea").focus();
        }
        console.log('Textarea => ' + $("#special-textarea").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="directorist-custom-field-checkbox">             
    <div class="directorist-checkbox directorist-mb-10" id="special-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Yes-3727648641" name="special-checkbox[]" value="Yes">
        <label for="Yes-3727648641" class="" id="special-checkbox-label">Special Instructions Specified</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="directorist-custom-field-textarea">
    <textarea name="special-textarea" id="special-textarea" class="directorist-form-element" rows="3" placeholder=""></textarea>    
</div>
```

Let me know whether this can help.

Comment: Yes, that code does work. I did wish it would not clear it if there was content in there already, but this is something I can just simply warn my client will happen if he toggles the checkbox.

Comment: Yes correct or you can check if the text value is something different than the specific string

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal!